# How do I resize webGL canvas in bootstrap.js column?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, webgl

I have a webpage at [here](http://pulleymaven.com/fancy/) where I want to resize a webGL drawing in an HTML5 canvas to fit within "6" columns using the [bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/) library for layout.

The layout is defined as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6" id="rightColDiv"><canvas id="lesson04-canvas" style="border: none;" width="1000" height="500"></canvas></div>
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following in a tick() function but still not getting the sizing I am looking for.

```
function tick() {
    requestAnimFrame(tick);
    drawScene();

   //    gl.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   //    gl.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

   // This is not returning a width
   var rightColDiv = document.getElementById("rightColDiv");
   var glwidth = rightColDiv.width;
//   gl.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - rightColDiv.width;
    gl.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 6/12; // 6 columns out of the 12
    document.getElementById("lesson04-canvas").width = window.innerWidth * 6/12;
  // gl.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

}
```

I think the questions are:

1) How do I get the width of the "columns" back when I use the boostrap.js library?
2) Do I need to set both the gl.canvas.width and the width of the "lesson04-canvas"?
3) Is the tick() function the most appropriate place to do this?

Comment: So you just want that the canvas does not go over the width of the col div?

Comment: I want to have the width of the canvas and the drawing area for the webGL equal to the width of <div class = "col-md-6" id="rightColDiv">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following to your css:

```
#rightColDiv canvas { 
  max-width:100%; 
}
```

Then it should fit the width of the col-md-6 div.